# d3 js add points to path transition example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Just starting out with D3.

Im trying to add points to the path transitions example when the y value is greater than .2 and transition them across the path so they appear to stay in the same location relative to the path. Its just a test to eventually apply to my own data but i dont really understand how i could do it. 
Heres a link to a jsfiddle with my attempt so far. Any pointers would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/yn7XY/

figured i could just do the below in the update, thanks

```
points = svg.selectAll("circle") .data([data])                       
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("opacity", function(d) {
if (d > .2) {
    return .9;}
else {
    return 0;
});
.style("fill", "DarkRed")
.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return x(i);})
.attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d);})
.attr("r", function(d) {return 4;})
.transition()
.duration(500)
.ease("linear")
.attr("transform", "translate("+ x(0) + ")")
.each("end", tick);

points.exit().remove();
```